# Is there a name for the form "فعلان" (faʿlan)?

Tags: terminology, arabic, semitic-languages

I've noticed the form فعلان (faʿlan) seems to imply emphasis, like in رحمان (raḥmân) which seems to means "All-Merciful". This form seems to exist in other Semitic languages like Hebrew (maybe רַבָּן, rabban?).

I've searched a while, but didn't find any answer. Does this form have a specific name in English?

Comment: I've never seen any names used for the Arabic forms except the traditional Arabic ones (so I would just call it "fa`lān"). Are there common names for the other forms in English, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Draconis, I'm thinking in term of common linguistic vocabulary like "causative form", "superlative", etc.

Comment: @Amessihel -- The suffix also occurs on collective plurals for mice, rats, lizards, and neighbors.

Comment: @bert-barrois, thanks. I haven't studied Arabic, so I'm just presuming. I think it's a matter of prefix like the examples you mentionned, but more of the pattern CaCCāN: raḥmān, sakrān. The pattern could also be CuCCāN like subḥān. They seem both to imply a completeness, and if so I'm surprised there is no linguistical term describing this form, especially if it's not just Arabic but Semitic related. I think I'm wrong, but don't know where.

Comment: I don't know Hebrew, but I think the suffix -ŌN might be cognate.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffixes_in_Hebrew) says it has diminutive connotation.

Comment: @BertBarrois, sorry I made typos in my previous comment. I meant it's more a matter of a _pattern_ than just a prefix. The link in the accepted answer below shows this case with an example, ʻaṭšān (thirsty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Wikipedia article [on Arabic Nouns and Adjectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_nouns_and_adjectives) the *fa'lan* form is named **intensive**.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it has a particular name, but it can be defined as forming adjectives from verbal stems, like sakrān “drunk” from s-k-r, or kaslān “lazy” from k-s-l. Normally, such adjectives have a human referent.

Comment: Thank you. Are sakrān and kaslān impliying "all-something"-like sense ("all-sugared" ie alcoholic, "all-lazyness") as I supposed in my comment replying  to @Bert-Barrois?

Comment: s1-k-r “to be drunk” is Semitic, not related to the Persian/Indian loanword for “sugar”.

Comment: Yes, it is loan word from Persian.